# Creating an android project does not create the R.java file for me and there appears to be gradle errors as well

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I had a problem with my android studio not creating the R.java file ( which its still not doing ) but ontop of that, im getting this error which I dont understand at all.

[image: Error 1]

as well as this error

[image: Error 2]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This might java error.
check your java version you might need to update your java.

Comment: i haveI jdk version 7, which is the one needed by android studio. How do I confirm if my java is the problem?